# Are there two CLR modules for python?

Tags: python, module, clr, python.net

I have been trying to use clr Addreference module and I keep getting the following error-
AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

I have installed pythonnet and so that is not the cause for this.

I was looking into the clr homepage, it says it is some styling library
https://pypi.org/project/clr/

I got around the problem by uninstalling the clr module and using clr which got activated when installing pythonnet.

Shouldnt someone look into this name conflict?